Конвертировать DEC в HEX ASCII
Как мне из int = 123 перекодировать в  31 32 33 HEX в таблице ASCII
Изначально мне нужно так, что у меня есть массив под длину символов int, делаю таким образом:

int mon = 123;
int count = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%i", mon);
char hexAsciimon[count];
sprintf(hexAsciimon, "%02X", mon);
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(hexAsciimon);i++){
        Serial.printf("%X\n", hexAsciimon[i]);
      }

но вывод такой 37 42 0, а не 31 32 33
Что не так и как правильно.

Вы нашли count для "%i", а заполняете массив "%02X", что будет совсем другой строкой. Если взять "%i", то получите ожидаемый вами результат.

@needKVAS, а на что мне нужно изменить?

Я заменил "%02X" на "%i" и вывел мне 31 32 33 , Спасибо большое! всем за ответ!

Я заменил %02X на %i и вывел мне 31 32 33.
